# Выходит из авторизации пользователя через 5 минут

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

Возникает проблема, что после авторизации через 5 минут пропадает авторизация, в startup:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
        {
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
            o.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
        });
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы авторизация не пропадала?

Comment: Очень хороший но и очень многогранный вопрос. См. тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/62770208/5752652 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/50228068/5752652 Версия asp.net core какая? Где хостимся - в IIS, IIS Express, nginx?

Comment: @AK, версия 3.1, в IIS хостимся

Comment: Если посмотреть в логи браузера, то в ответе от сервера на авторизацию, вам прилетает кука в заголовке `Set-Cookie`, там указано, сколько кука должна жить, а так же должна ли она экспайриться при закрытии браузера. На низком уровне вам нужно поправить как раз время жизни куки на "никогда не истекать".

Comment: @aepot, ну там стоит вчерашние число:
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=*; expires=Sun, 18 Apr 2021 11:09:29 GMT; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly

Comment: Заглянул в то, как делают, Яндекс к примеру выставляет свои трекинговые куки на 2 года в будущее.

Comment: @aepot, как я понимаю, их надо именно задавать в авторизации, а не в startup?

Comment: Я думаю, какие-то стандартные значения можно и в стартапе прописать, иначе было бы нелогично растаскивать настройки по контроллерам. На самом деле, я с ASP плохо знаком, но хорошо знаю, как работает веб на низкому уровне.

Comment: @aepot Сделал чтобы был год, но все равно вылетает через несколько минут, хотя и до этого был год, только заметил

Comment: У вас скорей всего засыпает от скуки IIS. Приложение останавливается и выданные тикеты забываются. Желательно настроить сохранение тикетов куда-либо. также можете настроить незасыпание, но это поможет только до первого перезапуска.

Comment: @4per, Спасибо оказалось, что проблема на стороне сервера, где размещался сайт. Они её решили и все хорошо